# python - matplotlib : figsize for subplots - adding space between rows

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using the following code to make plots:

```
   fig, axes = plt.subplots(len(pairs), 3, figsize=(12, 324))
    for i, pair in enumerate(pairs):
        d = pd.DataFrame(columns=[pairs[0], pairs[1]])
        e = df_norm[list(pair)]
        ax0 = axes[i,0]
        ax1 = axes[i,1]
        ax2 = axes[i,2]

        d[pair[0]] = np.random.normal(e[pair[0]],0.02)
        d[pair[1]] = np.random.normal(e[pair[1]],0.02)

    d.plot.scatter(*pair, ax=ax0, c=col0, linewidths=0, s=2, alpha = 0.7)
    d.plot.scatter(*pair, ax=ax1, c=col1, linewidths=0, s=2, alpha = 0.7)
    d.plot.scatter(*pair, ax=ax2, c=col2, linewidths=0, s=2, alpha = 0.7)

fig.tight_layout()
```

However, my output plot all messed up like:

[image]

I try to change `figsize=(12, 324)` by making 324 bigger or smaller, but neither helps. Is there a way I can put some spaces between each row so the figures won't mess up. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE].

Answer (score 38):

You need to ommit `fig.tight_layout()` and instead use [`subplots_adjust`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust).

```
plt.subplots_adjust(top = 0.99, bottom=0.01, hspace=1.5, wspace=0.4)
```

with some very extreme values. `hspace` is the vertical gap between subplots (most probably in units of the subplot-height).

`Figure` has the same `subplots_adjust` method, so you can decide which one to chose.

Answer (score 14):

In my opinion, the easiest way is to stick with [`fig.tight_layout`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/tight_layout_api.html) and use `h_pad` (for height) and `w_pad` (for width). For example:

`fig.tight_layout(h_pad=5, w_pad=5)`